# Long-term effects of exercise on inflammatory response in rheumatoid arthritis patients

Tags: arthritis, rheumatology

How does long-term exposure to consistent exercise in Rheumatoid Arthritis patients affect their inflammatory response, and what are the mechanisms for any such change if it is at all understood?

**Example**: if a cohort of individuals with RA who experience some base level of joint inflammation during periods of relative rest were to begin regular low-intensity exercise sufficient to cause a slightly higher level of inflammation post-workout, how would their profile of inflammatory responses be expected to change over time under this exercise regimen versus individuals who maintained sedentary lifestyles?

This question is concerned only with the inflammatory responses and not the risks of a sedentary lifestyle, so let's assume for the sake of this question that the "relative rest" of the sedentary cohort still comprises a healthy level of daily activity.

**Prior research:**

The reason I'm asking this question is because the information I have found online on this topic seems heavily concerned with the benefits of an active lifestyle, e.g. [This article on exercise aiding in joint function](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/rheumatoid-arthritis/in-depth/rheumatoid-arthritis-exercise/art-20096222#:%7E:text=But%20exercise%20is%20one%20of,flexibility%20can%20aid%20joint%20function.). Not being a medical scientist myself, I am struggling a bit with the more academic literature on the topic, and those that I have found are very general in nature. For example, [this paper on "Benefits of Exercise in Rheumatoid Arthritis"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3042669/) is also very general, and only had this to say on the disease itself;

> Exercise training for RA patients has been shown to be efficacious in
> reversing cachexia and substantially improving function **without**
> **exacerbating disease activity** and is likely to reduce cardiovascular
> risk. Thus, all RA patients should be encouraged to include aerobic
> and resistance exercise training as part of routine care.

I'm interested in a deeper understanding on the relationship between long-term exercise and inflammation in RA, without getting distracted by extended discussion on more general benefits of exercise. If there is a relationship between inflammation and long-term exercise, I'd also like to understand the biological mechanism for this.

Comment: @IanCampbell thanks, will do.

Comment: @IanCampbell is that better?